# How to get client and server token in Uber?

Tags: android, uber-api

Sorry for stupid question, but I can not register new app in Uber dashboard.

Here is the message:

> In order to create your Uber developer account, you must confirm your
>   mobile number. If you just signed up, please wait for the confirmation
>   message, and try again later.confirm your number

How to confirm phone number?
I send SMS with text "go" to their number and after get answer with some number. Where I should enter that number in my account? I didn't find the field.

What I am doing wrong?

Does anybody face with this problem?

Comment: Did you try opening up the Uber app? It should prompt you to validate your number. That's where you have to enter the number you received.

Comment: Which app? Uber partners, riders or just client app?

Comment: Did you sign up as a rider or driver?

Comment: In that case, open up the Uber Rider app. Please also ensure your phone number is correct on this screen or in the Rider app: https://riders.uber.com/profile

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1) You start with [this tutorial](https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/getting-started) and click on ["register an app"](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard/create). You end up on the login screen. Click on "Sign Up":
[image]

2) Fill out the form with your data and click on "Create Account":
[image]

3) You will be redirected to this screen on your website:
[image]

At the same time, you should receive an SMS:
[image]

4) Open up your Uber rider app and log in with your account credentials. It will prompt you to enter your code. The one you received before:
[image]
After that, your phone number is verified and Uber app opens regularly.

5) Finally, login to the [Uber Developer Dashboard](https://developer.uber.com/dashboard/create#_) to create a new Uber app
[image]

Comment: I have tried. I have registered new account via your website. Then downloaded Uber app for my android phone. I enter my registered email address and password. I throws me message "UNAUTHORIZED" and in second try it throws me "YOUR ACCOUNT IS DISABLED contact to support@uber.com". Why this is happening!? Third time. It is like Uber is deliberately trying to prevent me to use this app.